# Картинка в уведомлении из url

Tags: java, android

Я делаю уведомление для плеера, проблема заключается в том, что я получаю нужное мне изображение с помощью библиотеки Picasso, изображение у меня на хостинге.

Я пытался найти решение установки url изображения в уведомление, но найденные решения, либо не подходили, так как там использовался отдельный xml макет, либо устарели.

Comment: https://coderoad.ru/51450984/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-Bitmap-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-Picasso

Comment: @Circassian, не понял как мне использовать эти методы

Comment: Получаешь Bitmap от Picasso и вставляешь в setLargeIcon()

Comment: @Circassian, а как и где мне их вызывать? Просто на сайте не понятно расписано, что и как использовать, только вырванное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаешь `Bitmap` от `Picasso`

```
try {
    Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.get()
        .load("url")
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .get();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

и вставляешь в

```
setLargeIcon(bitmap)
```

Comment: вылетает, выполняю перед уведомлением, только немного изменил, сделал Bitmap bitmap; в главном классе и потом уже bitmap =.. перед уведомлением

Comment: Что пишет в логах?

Comment: В вопросе добавил

Comment: Ну ведь там вполне человеческим языком написано, что метод не должен вызываться в UI-thread